# Coupon collector’s test (for testing sequences)

Tags: statistics, sequence, probability, statistical-test

I'm reading Donald Knuth's The Art of Programming. I can't figure out how to apply chi-square. Here's the algorithm itself
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA722.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Pgj.png)

Let's say I have a sequence 1101221022120202001212201010201121. Then I "collect coupons" and get this array [5,3,5,5,6,5,5,5,4]. Further what to do with this array I do not understand. How to apply chi-square and what are these probabilities (pr and pt) for?

Comment: Welcome to SO! As written, this question appears to be asking for general statistics advice; it may more appropriate for Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Questions here must be about a specific programming problem (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Stack%20Overflow%20only%20accepts%20certain,it%20will%20likely%20be%20closed.). Please adjust your question according to the recommendations at the link or it may be closed.